# How to fix armature being seperate from mesh?

Tags: armature, pose-mode

My armature appears somewhat seperate from the mesh itself, can anyone help to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: unfortunately my .blend file exceeds the size limit of pasteall.org , but I do have an alternative.    https://we.tl/t-sik5YGdFI7    copy this link into your browser and then press the blue download button. It will start the download and you will get my blend file :)

Answer (score 0):

No wonder why the bones are not aligned with the mesh in *Pose* mode, they are not aligned in *Rest* pose either. You need to realign them in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks a lot moonboots :)